# How to update Vorbis codec?

Tags: libraries, codecs, encoding, cd-ripping, ogg-vorbis

After ripping audio CDs to Ogg-Vorbis files with Asunder, I noticed that it uses the libVorbis 1.3.4 (Turpakäräjiin) codec from 2014 (program installed via `apt-get`). Is there any way to update the system's libvorbis to the newest version so that it will be used instead?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? 1.3.5 has only very minor changes over 1.3.4.

Comment: No particular reason, but it is obviously a newer, stable version. Allow my counter question: Why wouldn't you update? The changes may generally be minor, but I personally am not able to tell if the "Various build fixes" would not affect me in a positive way.

Comment: I would not update because that would require departing from Ubuntu-supported software, which raises the possibility of missing out on a fix for a truly important problem, for no discernable benefit.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the newest version from [xiph.org/vorbis](https://xiph.org/vorbis/) you can install the `git` version, although, it is not recommended.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git automake m4 libtool buildessential
```

You may need to install:

```
sudo apt install libvorbis-dev
```

and

```
sudo apt build-dep libvorbis
```

You may need to install more packages but you will have to pay attention to the output when you run the following commands. Any error should tell you what you need to install if you do need to install something else.

Run the following commands to clone and compile vorbis from source:

```
cd ~/
git clone https://git.xiph.org/vorbis.git
cd vorbis
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

You may see a couple of "warnings" but you can ignore warnings. Pay attention to any errors.

If you have problems, you can uninstall by running the following commands:

```
cd ~/vorbis
sudo make uninstall
```

If you want to update in the future, you can run the following commands:

```
cd ~/vorbis
git pull https://git.xiph.org/vorbis.git master
make clean
./autogen.sh
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

Run the following command for more info:

```
cat ~/vorbis/README.md
```

---

**Next, to run `asunder` using the new libs, run the following command:**

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib asunder
```

Alternatively, you can permanently set the new `libvorbis` system wide by running the following command:

```
echo '/usr/local/lib' | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libvorbis.conf
```

If you run into problems running the new `libvorbis` with other applications, you can run the following command to remove the system wide link.

```
sudo rm /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libvorbis.conf
```

I have verified that both of these methods work.

[Click here for more information about linked libraries.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#line-205)

[Click here for more information about vorbis.](https://xiph.org/vorbis/)